# How to use .NET web service in iPhone, with POST method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, post

I am communicating with a .NET web service in an iPhone application, using the POST method, but I am not getting XML back as response. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Myserver/EventService.svc"]];

NSString *api = @"/registeruser";
NSData *body = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@",
    api, txtFName.text ,txtLName.text,
    txtUName.text, txtEmail.text, txtPassword.text,
    txtCity.text, txtState.text, str] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSLog(@"url %@",url);
NSLog(@"body %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@",
    api, txtFName.text, txtLName.text,
    txtUName.text, txtEmail.text, txtPassword.text,
    txtCity.text, txtState.text, str]);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSLog(@"body len %d",[body length]);

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *XMLString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data %@",XMLString);
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you getting as a response?

Comment: Is that the real URL address you are communicating with (*'Myserver/EventService.svc'*)? What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for replying me. I am getting blank(nothing) as response.

No that is not my actual server. My actual server is working and give xml back in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that with following.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Myserver/EventService.svc/webservice/%@/%@",para1,para2]]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:0 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response; 
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *XMLString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data %@",XMLString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something smaller first? Say doing an http post locally? Or doing an http post to that server with a simple html form?

I have run into this issue myself and decided to step back and start with a simple http post to make sure my objective-c was correct first.

I used [this tutorial](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/04/10/Submit-data-using-an-http-post-in-objective-c) to get me started -hope it helps